# Integratable local martingale is martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

> Show that an integratable local martingale $(X_t)_{t=1,...,T}$ is martingale. Is this true in continuous time $[0,\infty)$?

Let $(\tau_n)$ be a localising sequence for X (so $(\tau_n)$ stopping times with $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n=T)\to 1$). I need to show $$E(1_A(X_t-X_s))=0, s\leq t, A \in\mathcal{F}_s.$$ Since $X_{t\land\tau_n}$ is martingale, it holds $$E(1_A(X_{t\land\tau_n}-X_{s\land\tau_n}))=0\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s\leq t, A\in\mathcal{F}_s$$

If $$|1_A(X_{t\land\tau_n}-X_{s\land\tau_n})|\leq\max_{i=1,...,T}|X_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^T|X_i|<\infty \tag{1}$$ we can apply dominated convergence theorem:

Let $A\in\mathcal{F}_{s\land\tau_n}, s\leq t$, then  $$0= lim_{n\to\infty}E(1_A(X_{t\land\tau_n}-X_{s\land\tau_n}))\overset{\text{dom.Konv.}}{=}E(lim_{n\to\infty}1_A(X_{t\land\tau_n}-X_{s\land\tau_n}))=E(1_A(X_{t\land T}-X_{s\land T}))=E(1_A(X_{t}-X_{s})).$$
but is eq. (1) even true? As a hint was given: Show $X_{t\land \tau_n} \to X_t$ by considering $\mathbb{E} \sup_n |X_{t\land \tau_n}|$. I don't know why and how...

Comment: See the section in Le Gall’s Stochastic Calculus text on local times (I think it is the beginning of chapter 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good, there are just a few minor details that could be cleaned up:

I think (1) should have a factor of $2$ in it:
\begin{align*}
|1_A(X_{t \wedge \tau_n} - X_{s \wedge \tau_n})| \le |X_{t \wedge \tau_n}| + |X_{s \wedge \tau_n}| \le 2 \max_{i=1,...,T} |X_i| \le 2 \sum_{i=1}^T |X_i|.
\end{align*}

Also, to apply the dominated convergence theorem, we need that $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^T |X_i|] < \infty$ rather than just $\sum_{i=1}^T |X_i| < \infty$.  Both are true; this is just a minor detail.

This is not true in continuous time.  As a counterexample, one can consider the local martingale $M_t := \|B_t\|^{-1}$ where $B_t$ is a 3-dimensional Brownian motion with $B_0 = x \ne 0$.  It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404019/show-that-the-inverse-norm-of-brownian-motion-in-r3-is-uniformly-integrable/4412586#4412586) that $M$ is a local martingale and is uniformly integrable (in particular, $\mathbb{E}[M_t] < \infty$ for all $t$).  However, $M_t \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.  If $M$ were a martingale, we would have $M_t = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} M_s | \mathcal F_t] = 0,$ which is clearly not true.